# Pass specific Time Zone to Calendar Event

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

How do I pass an specific time zone when adding a new event to the calendar using my app? Say that my phone's default time zone is (GMT+1:00) London, Dublin.. I want to pass the (GMT+8:00) Hong Kong instead. Thanks.

I use something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", stime);
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
//intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", etime);
intent.putExtra("title", eventName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i think you have to convert your date with GMT +8:00 to current timezone of device.

Comment: i do not want to convert it to device's time zone. i want it only to use HongKong timezone for example.